# The slight differences in correlation coefficient results between using NumPy/Pandas and implementing the math directly in Python without packages?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

How come there is slight difference in correlation coefficient results between using NumPy/Pandas and implementing the math directly in Python without packages?

```
import random
random.seed(123)
x = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10000)]
y = [random.randint(50, 300) for _ in range(10000)]

# Numpy package
import numpy as np
np.corrcoef(x,y)[0, 1]
# 0.0022005615278884116

# Pandas package
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y':y})
df['x'].corr(df['y'])
# 0.0022005615278884116

# self-implementation 1
n = len(x)
sum_xy = sum([xi*yi for xi,yi in zip(x, y)])
sum_x = sum(x)
sum_y = sum(y)
sum_x_squared = sum([xi ** 2 for xi in x])
sum_y_squared = sum([yi ** 2 for yi in y])
(n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / ((n * sum_x_squared - (sum_x) ** 2)  * (n * sum_y_squared - (sum_y) ** 2))** (1/2)
# 0.0022005615278884103

# self-implementation 2
mean_x = sum(x) / len(x)
mean_y = sum(y) / len(y)
cov_xy = sum([(xi - mean_x)*(yi - mean_y) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)])
var_x = sum([(xi - mean_x) **2 for xi in x]) 
var_y = sum([(yi - mean_y) **2 for yi in y]) 
cov_xy / (var_x * var_y) ** (1/2)
# 0.0022005615278883955
```

They are all supposed to be Pearson's  correlation coefficient, so I expect the results should be the same for all. However, they turns out to be slightly different after 16 decimal places.

Comment: Algorithm #1 isn't the same algorithm. This algorithm for computing correlation is mathematically equivalent to what Pandas is doing, but suffers from numeric instability. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94056/instability-of-one-pass-algorithm-for-correlation-coefficient When subtracting two numbers from each other which agree in the first N bits, you lose up to N bits of accuracy in the result.

Comment: Despite the previous down-votes, I'm *up*-voting this because I think an answer around "numeric instability" will help both this inquirer and future inquirers. Sometimes exploring the flawed assumptions behind a question are more valuable than the question itself.